# uncaught TypeError: (t.data || "").search is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am new to angular, I am trying to display alert when I click each li, but I am getting an error

> uncaught TypeError: (t.data || "").search is not a function

can you guys tell me how to fix it.

relevant code and example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/M05wS03ynxX812u2MATc?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

```or-tag-here
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',

  styles: [`
    li {
      color: red;
    }
  `],
  template: `<ul class= "master">
                <li *ngFor ="let student of liArraycontent" (click) = "liClicked(this)"> {{student}} </li>
              </ul>`
})
export class AppComponent { 
  name = 'Angular';
  liArraycontent = ["testing 1", "testing 2", "testing3"]
  this.liClicked = function(e1) {
    alert('a');
  }


}


/*
Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
*/
```

Comment: The plunkr you linked doesn't give the error in your question but it does give several typescript compilation errors. Fix the compilation errors first, and then see if you still get the 'not a function' error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `this` at **typescript class**. just remove `this` in your component.

```
liClicked = function(e1) {
  alert(e1);
}
```

also when you use `this` at `template` event, you will get `AppComponent` which is different from javascript. And if you want to access current `li` element, use `$event.target` instead.

refer **[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/npNw39aRZVgpqEjI6uLH?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&p=preview)**, hope it'll help.

**BTW** I didn't got the error `(t.data || "").search is not a function` from the example you provided, maybe you need more explanation.